# Pass parameter to qsub : issues with brackets

Tags: parameters, brackets, qsub

I try to pass parameter to qsub :

```
text="some text (with brackets) in the middle"
qsub script.sh -v "text=\"$text\""
```

in script.sh I just print the `$text` field and it gives me

```
"some text (with brackets
```

So the string is truncated due to the ")" closing bracket. How to avoid that and have this result :

```
"some text (with brackets) in the middle"
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you mange to find a solution in the end?